# Formula breaks subtly in ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a spreadsheet document with a formula comparing a list of URLs to lists on two other sheets within the document.

I desire to know if each URL on the first list is present on the blocklist, whitelist, both, or neither.

Note that I have used named ranges on all three URL columns (minus the header, e.g. `'sheetname'!A2:A1000'`).

Here is my current formula:

```
=if(len(REQUESTS),if(AND(countif(BLOCK,REQUESTS),countif(WHITE,REQUESTS)),"ON BOTH",if(countif(BLOCK,REQUESTS),"Blocked",if(countif(WHITE,REQUESTS),"Whitelisted","Pending addition to a list"))),"")
```

This works as expected, except that I need to drag it down to each row in the sheet containing the requests.

When I add it to an `ARRAYFORMULA`, the `AND` no longer works. Any URL present in both BLOCK and WHITE returns "Blocked".

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(REQUESTS),if(AND(countif(BLOCK,REQUESTS),countif(WHITE,REQUESTS)),"ON BOTH",if(countif(BLOCK,REQUESTS),"Block",if(countif(WHITE,REQUESTS),"White","Pending addition to a list"))),""))

Actual location(s)  Working formula               With ARRAYFORMULA
neither             Pending addition to a list    Pending addition to a list
white               White                         White
block               Block                         Block
BOTH                ON BOTH                       Block
```

If it helps, when I swapped the `if(White)` and `if(Block)`, I get "White" when it is on both.

Any ideas why the addition of `ARRAYFORMULA` breaks my logic, or an alternative method of getting the formula to repeat as needed?

Comment: Stick-a-round Clay as it might take a while for n answer to arrive....Welcome on Web Applications !!

Comment: No worries and thanks for the welcome.

Comment: Hi Clay, would it be possible to share a copy of your spreadsheet so we can take a closer look ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In array formulas instead of `AND` and `OR` functions use `*` and `+` respectively.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LC78Vk8KNSlkxebzftNlJqtYgZUwAQfy1TtNJBGf7gY/edit?usp=sharing)

AND: Instead of

`=ArrayFormula(and(A2:A4,B2:B4))`

use

`=ArrayFormula(A2:A4*B2:B4)`

OR: Instead of

`=ArrayFormula(or(A2:A4,B2:B4))`

use

`=ArrayFormula(A2:A4+B2:B4)`